# Testing Nifi class with nested dependency

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I write junit for org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateRecord processor in Apache Nifi?
Here is my code

```
@Test
public void valiateRecordTest() throws IOException {

       ValidateRecord validateRecord = new ValidateRecord();
       
       TestRunner runner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(validateRecord); 
       String inputJson = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("validateRecordInput.json"));
       String inputSchema = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("validateRecordInputSchema.json"));
       String expectedResult = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("validateRecordOutput.json"));
       
       //runner.setProperty(ValidateRecord.SCHEMA_REGISTRY, inputSchema);
       MockRecordParser reader = new MockRecordParser();
       runner.addControllerService("reader", reader);           
       runner.setProperty("Record Reader","JsonTreeReader");
       runner.setProperty("Record Writer","JsonRecordSetWriter");
       runner.setProperty("service", "reader");
       
       runner.setProperty(reader,"Schema Registry","AvroSchemaRegistry"); //for JsonTreeReader
       runner.setProperty(reader,"Schema Text",inputSchema); //for JsonRecordSetWriter
       runner.enableControllerService(reader);
       runner.enqueue(inputJson);
       runner.run(1);
       runner.assertQueueEmpty();
       List<MockFlowFile> resultList = runner.getFlowFilesForRelationship("valid");         
       ........
}
```

JsonTreeReader has got other parameters like Avro schema. How do I set it?  (As I am not passing an instance of JsonTreeReader here). I am getting following error

```
'Record Reader' is invalid because Record Reader is required
'Record Writer' is invalid because Record Writer is required
'Record Reader' validated against 'JsonTreeReader' is invalid because 'Record Reader' is not a supported property or has no Validator associated with it
'Record Writer' validated against 'JsonRecordSetWriter' is invalid because 'Record Writer' is not a supported property or has no Validator associated with it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestRunner has methods on it for adding and enabling controller services. Something like this:

```
def reader = new MockRecordParser()
runner.addControllerService("reader", reader)
runner.setProperty(SomeDescriptor, "reader")
runner.enableControllerService(reader)
```

You can set properties like this:

```
runner.setProperty(reader, DESCRIPTOR_HERE, "myvalue")
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike Thomsen for the response.  I edited my code according to the suggestion. I am getting following error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Controller service MockRecordParser[id=reader] cannot be modified because it is not disabled
 at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.getConfigToUpdate(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:760)
 at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.setProperty(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:778)
 at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.setProperty(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:807)
 at com.nifi.test.FlowTest.valiateR.

Comment: It has to be disabled before you can set properties on it. Think of it like "live NiFi" where you are not allowed to update a running component.

Comment: Correct @Mike Thomson. That error has gone. Now I am getting ''Schema Text' is not a supported property or has no Validator associated with it
 at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.enableControllerService(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:703)

Comment: Take a look at this example for how to start setting the properties for readers correctly: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/c396927299586b896df4ebc745793b4c451f3898/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-mongodb-bundle/nifi-mongodb-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/mongodb/PutMongoRecordIT.java#L231

Comment: The SchemaAccessUtils defines all of the constants that you'll need to use for configuring that stuff. If you do a search for JsonTreeReader in our github repo, you can find nearly two dozen examples of this sort of test.